# JSON Array - Powershell

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I need an JSON array string like the following: `[{"a":"1","b":"2","c“:"3","d": "4"}]`

If I am using the following code, I am getting `{medik:[{"a":"1","b":"2","c“:"3","d": "4"}]}`

```
$body = @{
   medik =  @(
        @{
            a = '1'
            b = '2'
            c = '3'
            d = '4'
        }
    )
}
$jsbody=$body|ConvertTo-Json -Compress;
$jsbody
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `medik =  `

Answer (score 1):

Try it without using the pipeline.

When using the pipeline you are passing the array one hashtable at a time to ConvertTo-Json. Since there is only one hashtable, it is seen as a single hashtable not an array of hashtables.

```bsh
ConvertTo-Json @(@{a = '1'; b = '2'; c = '3'; d = '4'})
```

Output:

```bsh
PS C:\tmp\overflow> $body = @(@{a = '1'; b = '2'; c = '3'; d = '4'})
>> ConvertTo-Json $body

[
  {
    "d": "4",
    "c": "3",
    "b": "2",
    "a": "1"
  }
]
```

Comment: Not a problem. If you feel this is the correct answer, please remember to mark it as accepted.